# Plural with conjunction

Tags: grammatical-number

Which is correct use with 'and'
New and used tires sales and services.
Or
New and used tire sales and services.

I want to know whether the tire is singular or plural in above sentences.

Comment: Syntactically speaking, both versions are "valid", but in practice we normally treat *[new and used] **tire*** as an "attributive" noun (used to modify another noun) in such contexts. In this case, the "composite" noun  being modified is *sales and **service***, not plural *services*. Google Books has 4 instances of [*New and used **tire** sales*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22New+and+used+tire+sales%22), but none at all with plural ***tires***.

Comment: @FF 'Services' would be common to introduce a list of providers in say Yellow Pages. //// HNY.